# Fluent NHibernate Mapping of Entity to Two Tables Joined by Non-Primary Key Column

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have the following entity and entity properties:

```
public class UserContact
{
    public virtual ulong ContactId {get; set;}
    public virtual ulong UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual ulong ContactUserId {get; set;}
    public virtual string ContactFirstNm {get; set;}
    public virtual string ContactLastNm {get; set;}
}
```

My database schema contains the following view and table with columns:

```
CONTACT_VIEW
    CONTACT_ID
    USER_ID
    CONTACT_USER_ID

USERS
    USER_ID
    FIRST_NM
    LAST_NM
```

I am attempting to create my mapping class such that I can join the view and the table on CONTACT_VIEW.CONTACT_USER_ID to USERS.USER_ID. I do not know, however, how to do this join mapping.

```
public UserContactMap()
{
    Table("CONTACT_VIEW");
    CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ContactId, "CONTACT_ID")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.UserId, "USER_ID");
    Map(x => x.ContactUserId, "CONTACT_USER_ID");
    Join("USERS", jx =>
    {
        //what do i put here?
        jx.Map(x => x.ContactFirstNm, "FIRST_NM");
        jx.Map(x => x.ContactLastNm, "LAST_NM");
    };
}
```

**EDIT:**

With modifications to my entity (and creating another entity), I was able  to achieve the same effect of my original goal. However, I'm not convinced that there is not a way to do it similar to the way my mapping is laid-out above.

```
public class UserContact
{
    public virtual ulong ContactId {get; set;}
    public virtual ulong UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual ulong ContactUserId {get; set;}
    public virtual UserContactDetail ContactDetail {get; set;}
}

public class UserContactDetail
{
    public virtual ulong UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual string FirstNm {get; set;}
    public virtual string LastNm {get; set;}
}

//map constructor
public UserContactMap()
{
    Table("CONTACT_VIEW");
    CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(x => x.ContactId, "CONTACT_ID")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.UserId, "USER_ID");
    Map(x => x.ContactUserId, "CONTACT_USER_ID");
    References(x => x.ContactDetail , "CONTACT_USER_ID");
}

//map constructor
public ContactDetailMap()
{
    Table("USERS");
    Id(x => x.UserId, "USER_ID");
    Map(x => x.FirstNm, "FIRST_NM");
    Map(x => x.LastNm, "LAST_NM");
}
```

Does anyone know a more elegant solution (with just a join of two tables to create a single entity). I don't like the fact that I had to create another entity just to get my original  entity "working."

Comment: Have you tried to create an xml mapping or attribute mapping first? The fluent mapping is not too well documented, but most of the time I got success using Intellisense after I found an example about xml mapping somewhere.

Comment: @wigy - I haven't tried an xml mapping yet. Are you suggesting to just try to get it working in xml, and then try to mimic the mapping in fluent?

Comment: Yip. That is how I solved some of my NHibernate quests.